# function inside a view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i'm a newbie in `ci`, can anyone help me or give some suggestions in my code and best practice? i have a `foreach` statement that require to use a function for displaying a huge data. here's my sample code of view.
Thank you in advance

```
 foreach($data->result() as $d){

    if($d->condi){
       $sample =   myfunction($d->value1, $d->value2, $value->3);
    } 
    else{ 
         $d->otherdisplay;
            if($d->condition2){
            $sample =   myfunction($d->value1, $d->value2, $value->3);
            }
    }
}
function myfunction($a,$b,$c){
       /*do something;*/

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends , anyway these kind of `methods` should be in `controllers` or in `libraries`, it depends if your method `can be called from browser or not`.

If you want to use some method that you need to makesome `routine action` use a

```
library or an helper
```

If you want to use a `web page method` use that in `controller`

```
 Model = SQL and db stuffs

 Controller = all the php stuffs + data returned from Model

 View = html/js + data returned from Controller
```

Check [How to create Own libraries in CI](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Comment: thank you, by the way how can i create my own helper or library in ci? tnx again

Comment: @BasciBsu you're welcome just look at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html it's really simple and you will enojy them ;)

Comment: @BasciBsu do not forget to check the answer if i give you all the infos you needed ;)

Comment: tnx you so much, and lastly i can call my helper inside my view right? :)

Comment: @BasciBsu yep CI is really simple  ;) enjoy that and have nice coding time ;)

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to create a helper file in CI, and put this function in the helper file. 
Create you helper file in **'application/helpers'** directory
Then include this helper in the controller which is calling this view,
Like

`$this->load->helper('name');`

And now, you can use all the functions of the helper file directly in your view without any codeigniter instance.

Helpers, as the name suggests, help you with tasks. Each helper file is simply a collection of functions in a particular category.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

You should put your functions in the controller classes as much as possible (or somewhere else, as long as you call them from the controller). Parse your data there and then loop through it in the view. This keeps your code clean and organized and keeps true to the MVC principle.

Comment: i'd seem a sample code like this

controller $data['method'] = $this->method();

and in my 

view $method->method(param)??

is this a best practice??