# Can not access variables from a function in the view

Tags: php, codeigniter, scope

I'm using a function to generate some HTML in the view. I can not access the data that send form controller within that function.Following is the simplified code.

**Controller**

```
$data["var"] = "something";
$this->load->view("the_view",$data);
```

**View**

```
function some(){
   global $var;
   echo $var;
}

some(); //not working
echo $var; //working
```

I can move this function to the controller. Generate HTML in controller and send the generated HTML to view. But I like to keep HTML stuf in the view. How can I do this ?

Comment: so, basically you want the `var` from the `view` to be shown inside `some()`?

Comment: The controller basically will deal with raw data and generate the result data, that data needs to display in the view. In the view page, you have to render/display that data with proper UI elements. Don't overhard controller with some HTML render feature, bad practice?

Comment: @sauhardnc yes. Actually, I need to access data send by the controller to generate HTML. Proccess is complex. Also, It is recursive function.

Comment: both the answers currently should help you.

Comment: @sauhardnc Do you know the reason to this behaviour ?

Comment: @Dum The only thing in this matter I can say is that the `views` are not supposed to have a function. If you want a function in the view, you should create a 1library` or a 
 `helper`. See more - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807145/function-inside-a-view-in-codeigniter and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588195/codeigniter-global-variables-in-a-controller

Answer (score 1):

```js
You can rewrite your  function like this

function some($var){
   echo $var;
}

some($var);

Hope it will work
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It will work, but `some` is a recursive function. So, It is better if I can access the original data send by controller.

Comment: I think you want to receive data as array right... If so then you can send data from controller

like $data['var']=array('1','2','3'.....)

then call show($var);

Answer (score 0):

You have created an array named as data and var stored into that, so you need to this

```
function some($data){
   echo $data["var"];
}

some($data);
```

And in case your data array is global, then

```
function some(){
   global $data
   echo $data["var"];
}

some();
```